# Camel timer to read from a queue

Tags: apache-camel, jms

How to write a camel route
with timer..which will read from a jms queue

I have tried like this but not working
example

```
from(timer:mytimer)
.from("jms:queue)
```

Please let me know if there is any way

Comment: See the content enricher EIP pattern, and the pollEnrich method.

Comment: @ClausIbsen thanks for the reply have gone through http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html this doc i could see timeout and  wait but how to run a timer with the means i want repeat the process.

Comment: What is the use-case for using a timer? The best solution would just to read from the queue directly, so when there is a new message its routed asap. Otherwise if you still want a timer, then its just: from timer pollEnrich jms